# Data frame difference between `h2o.parseRaw` and `h2o.import_sql_table`

Tags: h2o

I try to load data from database into h2o for R modeling analysis.

I can get a data frame successfully with h2o function `h2o.import_sql_table()` like instruction at [here](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/building-h2o-glm-model-using-postgresql-database-and-jdbc-driver/). But this data frame can't be applied with h2o functions like: `h2o.hist()`, `as.data.frame()` and many more others which are used in [this](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/rdemo.airlines.delay.large.R). That makes me impossible to follow the demo steps to analyze data frames generated from `h2o.import_sql_table()`.

I want to know what differences are between data frames created by `h2o.import_sql_table()` and `h2o.parseRaw()`. And ideally, are there any methods that can convert data frames created by `h2o.import_sql_table()` into more traditional h2o data frames? Any code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avkash (answered below) is right -- they should both produce an H2OFrame and so you can use any of the H2OFrame methods like `h2o.hist()` etc on the output.  If you don't get an H2OFrame as the result of `h2o.import_sql_table()`, then something went wrong (maybe the connection URL is incorrect?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ingest data using h2o.importFile and h2o.import_sql_table, both the objects are H2OFrame as shown in the code snippet below:

```
> payment = h2o.import_sql_table(connection_url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dvdrentaldb?&useSSL=false", table= "payment", username = "avkash", password = "avkash")

|====================================================| 100%

> class(payment)
  [1] "H2OFrame"

> a1 = h2o.importFile("/Users/avkashchauhan/src/github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/smalldata/junit/cars.csv")
  |=======================================| 100%
> class(a1)
  [1] "H2OFrame"
```

If you want to show the histogram on a frame from h2o.import_sql_table, you can do the same as below:

```
> h2o.hist(payment$staff_id)
```

[image]

So they both are H2OFrame and all the functions on H2OFrame are applied as any other H2OFrame.

Please use h2o.importFile instead of h2o.parseSetup/h2o.parseRaw which are designed to perform 2 step parsing on an existing H2OFrame instead of a data source i.e. file location on disk, or HDFS or web location.

If you will use h2o.importFile and h2o.import_sql_table you will get H2OFrame all the functions will be same between these two.